# How to solve the index out of range problem of list using sum?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm a newbie in python and I'm trying to calculate the occurrence of an element in a 2 dimensional list using a for-loop. If the occurrence> 3 then:

> 1. Insert the element in list_2
> 2. Delete the element in list_1.

Unluckily, i get an index out of range error.

The variables i use:

```
data        # numpy array for a series of value
list_1      # a 2-dimensional list for data
list_2      # a list for data after some modification
```

create the array

```
import numpy as np
data=np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1,3])
```

I hope to refer the list by index later so  i create the 2 lists with given a length=9

```
list_1=[0 for i in range(0,9)]
list_2=[0 for i in range(0,9)]
```

Then assign each element in list_1 with a new list named node.

node will be like the subset of list_1.

```
for k in range(0,9):
node=[data[k],k]   
list1[k]=node
```

> There are 2 values in node.
> The first value is for data[i] , and the second value is for the index i.

For example:

```
node[i][0]=the value in data[i]
node[i][1]=the index of data[i], which is i
```

Here are my code.The error happens in the line :

> sum_count=sum(sublist.count(list1[i][0]) for sublist in list1)

```
# if list_1 is not empty
while list_1:   
    for i in range(0,9):
        # sum the occurrence of current element
        sum_count=sum(sublist.count(list_1[i][0]) for sublist in list_1)
        
        if sum_count>=3:
            index=list_1[i][1]
            list_2[index]=list_1[i][0]
            list_1.remove(list_1[i])
        else:      
            break
```

I have checked the value in index =0,1,2...8 ,respectively.
The
I have no idea what's wrong with the index. I'll be very grateful if anyone could give me some advice!

Comment: From your code, it seems like length of list_1 will be decreased but you are iterating over the original length. i.e. if you remove one element from list_1, new length will be 8, but you are accessing list_1[8] which is out of bounds

Comment: side note: you dont have to use list comprehension to pad a list. You could just do ~ `list_1 = [0]*8`

Comment: @AbhishekKuvalekar I have changed the range of i from(0,9) to( 0,len(list_1) ) and the error  is fixed.  Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelGuidry  thanks!